# After insert, delete on other table trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want a trigger that deletes the row in `user_briefcases` after a row is inserted in `user_briefcases_sold`

both tables have `briefcase_id` and `user_id`

I have no idea why this wont work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_user_briefcase_when_sold
DELIMITER $$ 
AFTER INSERT ON user_briefcases_sold FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
DELETE FROM user_briefcases WHERE briefcase_id = NEW.briefcase_id && user_id = NEW.user_id; 
END; 
$$ DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Why not use one table and add an `is_sold` column?

Comment: Move the `DELIMITER` statement _before_ the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement. The statements you have posted are not valid syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error 
try this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE 
  TRIGGER delete_user_briefcase_when_sold AFTER INSERT 
  ON user_briefcases_sold 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    DELETE FROM user_briefcases WHERE briefcase_id = NEW.briefcase_id AND user_id = NEW.user_id; 
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```